# Routing error in rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Rails noob here. I am using carrierwave in a rails 3 app so users can upload a profile picture. I set up a separate model, controller and views (profile_pictures) to handle this. To avoid making errors i use scaffold as a starting point.

route file:

```
resources :profile_pictures
```

rake routes:

```
edit_profile_picture GET    /profile_pictures/:id/edit(.:format)           {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profile_pictures"}
```

link to edit.html.erb:

```
<%= link_to "profile picture", edit_profile_picture_path %>
```

error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"profile_pictures"}
```

Side Note: I am constantly running into problems with routes... its driving me nuts. I've found numerous pages regarding conversion of prior routing format to rails 3 routes. Is there a basic tutorial on routes that explains all the nubbies? ... preferably in rails 3 format but a prior version is ok if that is all there is.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<%= link_to "profile picture", edit_profile_picture_path(@picture) %>`

Becouse you have a route `/profile_pictures/:id/edit`, @picture == :id

Answer (score 3):

First of all the route helper is not working because it is expecting an object or id as part of the call so where you have:

> <%= link_to "profile picture", edit_profile_picture_path %>

You need to have something like:

> <%= link_to "profile picture", edit_profile_picture_path(@user) %>

Where user would be the object that you'd want to use in your profile pictures controller. Using edit without an object is a common error when addressing routes.